# How to decode a string using regex?

Tags: python, regex, string, encryption, decoder

I have a file which contains data of users in rows which is stored in some cryptic format. I want to decode that and create a dataframe

> sample row -- AN04N010105SANDY0205SMITH030802031989

Note-
`AN04N01` is standard 7 letter string at the start to denote that this row is valid.

1. Here `0105SANDY` refers to 1st column(name) having length 5

- *01* -> 1st column ( which is name column )
- *05* -> length of name ( Sandy )

2. Similarly,`0205SMITH` refers to

- *02* -> 2nd column ( which is surname column )
- *05* -> length of surname ( Smith )

3. Similarly,`030802031989` refers to

- *03* -> 3rd column ( DOB )
- *08* -> length of DOB

I want a data frame like --

```
| name | surname | DOB |
|Sandy  | SMITH | 02031989 |
```

I was trying to use regex, but i don't know how to put this into a data frame after identifying names, also how will you find the number of characters to read?

Comment: Are the column number and length of data always two-digits?

Comment: What have you tried so far ? And do you have other examples or invalid strings ? Please edit your question to add those.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using regex for groups that might be out of order and varying length, it might be simpler to consume the string in a serial manner.

With the following, you track an index `i` through the string and consume two characters for `code`, then `length` and finally the variable amount of characters given by `length`. Then, you store the values in a `dict`, append the `dict`s to a list and turn that `list` of `dict`s into a dataframe. Bonus, it works with the elements in any order.

```py
import pandas as pd

test_strings = [
    "AN04N010105ALICE0205ADAMS030802031989",
    "AN04N010103BOB0205SMITH0306210876",
    "AN04N0103060101010104FRED0204OWEN",
    "XXXXXXX0105SANDY0205SMITH030802031989",
    ]

code_map = {"01": "name", "02": "surname", "03": "DOB"}

def parse(s):
    i = 7
    d = {}
    while i < len(s):
        code, i = s[i:i+2], i+2  # read code
        length, i = int(s[i:i+2]), i+2  # read length
        val, i = s[i:i+length], i + length  # read value
        d[code_map[code]] = val  # store value
    return d

ds = []

for s in test_strings:
    if not s.startswith("AN04N01"):
        continue
    ds.append(parse(s))

df = pd.DataFrame(ds)
```

`df` contains:

```
    name surname       DOB
0  ALICE   ADAMS  02031989
1    BOB   SMITH    210876
2   FRED    OWEN    010101
```

Answer (score 0):

here it is the code for this pattern :

```
(\w{2}\d{2}\w{1}\d{2})(\d{4}\w{5}\d+\w{5})(\d+)
```

or use this pattern :

```
(\D{5})\d+(\D+)\d+(02\d+)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
def fn(x):
    rv, x = [], x[7:]
    while x:
        _, n, x = x[:2], x[2:4], x[4:]
        value, x = x[: int(n)], x[int(n) :]
        rv.append(value)
    return rv


m = df["row"].str.startswith("AN04N01")
df[["NAME", "SURNAME", "DOB"]] = df.loc[m, "row"].apply(fn).apply(pd.Series)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                                     row   NAME SURNAME       DOB
0  AN04N010105SANDY0205SMITH030802031989  SANDY   SMITH  02031989
1  AN04N010105BANDY0205BMITH030802031989  BANDY   BMITH  02031989
2  AN04N010105CANDY0205CMITH030802031989  CANDY   CMITH  02031989
3  XXXXXXX0105DANDY0205DMITH030802031989    NaN     NaN       NaN
```

---

Dataframe used:

```
                                     row
0  AN04N010105SANDY0205SMITH030802031989
1  AN04N010105BANDY0205BMITH030802031989
2  AN04N010105CANDY0205CMITH030802031989
3  XXXXXXX0105DANDY0205DMITH030802031989
```

Comment: `fn` is a terrible name for a function.